Mocking Value not working when passing through mockReturnValue
I'm trying to create some unit tests using jest and I'm trying to mock a simple value. It works when I pass the mock directly, but since I'm trying to test different scenarios, it isn't working when I use mockReturnValue.
Here's the code I'm testing:
import { IS_IOS } from 'someDependency';
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';
import { KeyboardAvoidProps } from './types';

export const KeyboardAvoid: FC<KeyboardAvoidProps> = (props) => {
  const { children, contentContainerStyle, style, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={IS_IOS ? 'padding' : undefined}
      contentContainerStyle={[
        styles.contentContainerStyle,
        contentContainerStyle,
      ]}
      style={[styles.keyboardAvoidingView, style]}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={50}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

When I use
const mockIS_IOS = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);

jest.mock('someDependency', () => ({
  IS_IOS: mockIS_IOS(),
}));

it returns mockIS_IOS is not a function.
However, if I do
jest.mock('someDependency', () => ({
  IS_IOS: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true)()
}));

it works without any problem. Any ideas?
